# How can Cramer-von Mises not explode for large samples?

Tags: goodness-of-fit

The tests I am asking about are from this paper: http://www.nber.org/papers/w3349.pdf

I am running periodogram-based tests to see if I can test for whiteness of a data set.

[image]

I generate white noise in R using:

```
    library(varbvs)
    rand <- randn(1000,1)
```

Then I compute the cumulative periodogram and sum the squared deviations of the cumulative periodogram from the diagonal (which is what a cumulative periodogram of white noise should look like).

I am however confused as to how the Cramer- Von Mises test statistic won't be very large for large sample sizes since it's formula is:

[image]

Even if the deviations are very small, we are possibly multiplying positive small quantities by their total, so if i generate white noise with sample size 1000, I am bound to get a large cramer statistic, even though the cumulative periodogram is almost exactly the diagonal. Am I constructing the test wrong?
Here is my code:

```
    rand <- randn(1000,1)
    cump = function (x) 
    {
      data = x
      N = length(data)
      FT = abs(fft(data))^2
      q <- (N+1)/2
      periodogram = FT[1:q]/var(data)
      answer <- cumsum(periodogram)/sum(periodogram)
      wp <- (1:q)/(1 * q)
      return(list(wp = wp, cumperiod = answer, q = q, I=periodogram, freq = freq))
    }

    bridge = function (x){
      data = x
      m <- cump(data)
      plot(m$wp, m$cumperiod, type = "l", xlab = "w", ylab ="Cumulative Normalized Periodogram", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
```

lines(seq(0,1,length.out=length(m$wp)), seq(0,1,length.out=length(m$wp)), lty = 2, col = 2)
          b <- sqrt(2 * ((length(x)+1)/2)) * (m$cumperiod - (1:m$q)/ m$q)
          return(b)
        }
        Cm = function (x){
          data = x
          b = bridge(data)
          cm =  sum(b^2)
          return(cm)
        }
This is my cumulative deviations. Clearly this data is very close to white noise and so my statistic should be small.
[image]

Comment: Could you please tell us what you mean by a "cramer statistic"?  What formula do you have for it? There are several different tests and statistics that go by similar names and, since you question the code, we certainly can't rely on that to reveal what the statistic should be!

Comment: I just added a picture of it's formula. I(w) is the periodogram estimates of spectral density.

Comment: What book or document are you showing images of? Please offer proper referencing of the source(s)

Comment: Just added the paper that uses this test.